# Get crash logs from device through code iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a requirement to show the number of crashes that have occurred in my application. Is there any way to read the number of crashes from the device logs?

I am able to get the console by adding the following code and saving it as log file.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.log",[NSDate date]];

NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

But I need the console when the app crashed. Is there any way to do so?.

Comment: When you say read what do you mean ? You can see this information in the device logs.

Comment: I can see the device logs but I would like to show the number of crashes (count) to the user with in the application @GuybrushThreepwood

Comment: I am using crashlytics, My app can be used in offline mode, I would like to show the count even if it crashes in offline mode @SimonMcLoughlin

Comment: Unless you track / record them yourself I don't think you can do this. Sounds like a strange requirement. Crashlytics will update the next time the user connects to the internet also. Showing the end user crash information is not typically something that people do, its normally abstracted away from them, also for security reasons, crash info can contain info that could be used against the app. Discovering it uses vulnerable libraries etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `PLCrashReporter` https://www.plcrashreporter.org/

Comment: I am using crashlytics, My app can be used in offline mode, I would like to show the count even if it crashes in offline mode @rounak